# Prove that $BP$ goes through the midpoint of $EF$

Tags: geometry, circles

Given triangle $ABC$ (not isosceles), which is inscribed in the circle $(O)$, has three altitudes $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ intersecting at $H$. $AD$ intersects $(O)$ at $G$ ($G\neq A$) and $GE$ intersects $(O)$ at $P$ ($P\neq G$). Prove that $BP$ goes through the midpoint of $EF$.
[image]

I do not figure out any strategies to solve this. I think there might be some lemmas or similar problems relating to my exercise. Please help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $M$ be the midpoint of the $EF$-side of the orthic triangle. It is enough to show that $MFB$ and $EHG$ are similar. It is simple to prove that $\widehat{BFM}=\widehat{BFE}=\widehat{GHE}=\widehat{DHE}=\pi-C$ by angle chasing. By the properties of the [orthic triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthicTriangle.html) ($AEF$ and $ABC$ are similar) $FE=a\cos A$, while $FB=a\cos B$. It follows that 
$$\frac{FM}{FB}=\frac{a\cos A}{2a\cos B}=\frac{\cos A}{2\cos B}.$$
The distances of the orthocenter $H$ from the $AC$ and $BC$-sides are given by 
$$ HD = BD\cot C = c \cos B \cot C = 2 R \cos C \cos B $$
$$ HE = AE\cot C = c \cos A \cot C = 2 R \cos C \cos A $$
hence $\frac{FM}{FB}=\frac{HE}{HG}$ and we are done.